# why won't this code ever output 'yay'

Tags: python

I'm trying to output 'yay' in this python program, and it will only output 'nay'. I'm assuming I'm not using my if statement correctly. If someone could help me I'd appreciate it. I'm having this semantic issue on a much larger scale with a larger program but I just scaled the problem down to a smaller statement that's supposed to implement the same logic. any ideas?

```
    input1 = input("enter 2")
    input2 = input('enter 1')

    if input1 == 2 and input2 ==1:
            print('yay')
    else:
            print('nay')
```

Comment: @chipChocolate.py There is nothing wrong with it in Python 2, but there is in Python 3.

Comment: @AlexThornton - Yeah! You are right

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert your inputs to `int` :

```
input1 = int(input("enter 2"))
input2 = int(input('enter 1'))

if input1 == 2 and input2 ==1:
        print('yay')
else:
        print('nay')
```

Comment: in my other program I'm validating inputs that are strings and I'm having the same issue

Comment: @ClarkJarvis , are you do that same this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs are strings. You can convert your inputs to integers, and compare integer to integer, or keep it as a string and covert 1;2 to strings.

- Convert numbers to strings.

> ```
> input1 = input("enter 2")
> input2 = input("enter 1")
>
> if input1 == '2' and input2 =='1':
>         print('yay')
> else:
>         print('nay')
> ```

- Or convert the input to integers.

> ```
> input1 = int(input("enter 2"))
> input2 = int(input("enter 1"))
>
> if input1 == 2 and input2 ==1:
>         print('yay')
> else:
>         print('nay')
> ```